# Proof that cross product transforms like a vector?

Tags: vector-analysis

Given that $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ are vectors, how does one prove that $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}$ transforms like a vector under (proper) rotations?

I also know we can argue this using the Levi-Civita tensor, but I was unable to prove this without this fanciness.

Comment: It's an axial vector. They do not transform like vectors as far as I know. Having said that, you could try to use simple matrix multiplication to show the invariance under a particular transformation.

Comment: What do you mean by "transforms like a vector"? If $\vec{a} = \hat{i}$ and $\vec{b} = \hat{j}$, and you rotate these two in the $xy$ plane, their cross product is unchanged. How are you defining the operation of a rotation on the cross product? Via some sort of coproduct law?

Comment: @Cameron: I think what he means is that for $T$ a rotation, $T(a \times b) = Ta \times Tb$.

Comment: I mean that the components transform under a rotation like $v'^i = \frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^j} v^j$

Comment: A very similar question is answered in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167230/invariance-of-cross-product-under-coordinates-rotation .

Answer (score 2):

By a bit of algebra using the definition of cross product, you can satisfy yourself that:

$$a \cdot (a \times b) = 0$$
$$(a \times b) \cdot b = 0$$
$$|a \times b|^2 = |a|^2 |b|^2 - |a \cdot b|^2$$

From the last result, the magnitude of the cross product is invariant when $a, b$ are rotated. From the first two, it is orthogonal to them, and therefore rotates with them. One tricky detail is its direction (right hand or left hand), but by a continuity argument the result follows.