# Uniqueness of cross product

Tags: vectors, cross-product

My professor in E&M told us that the cross product is the only possible product of vectors that produces another vector.  I didn't ask him what he meant by that because he is Russian and can't always translate what he means into English very well.  How is the cross product the unique product which produces another vector?  Couldn't we define a bunch of other products like $(a,b,c)\times_1(d,e,f) = (ad,be,cf)$ or $(a,b,c)\times_2(d,e,f) = (ae,2bd,cf)$ or even just $(a,b,c)\times_3(d,e,f) = \frac{1}{2}(a,b,c)\times (d,e,f)$ (where the RHS is half the regular cross product)?  Are these things somehow *not vectors*?

---

EDIT: I started wondering if their was some invariant of vectors that the cross product preserves that other products don't.  Searching this site I found [that cross products are invariant under rotations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167230/invariance-of-cross-product-under-coordinates-rotation).  I wonder if that is it.  Is it true that the cross product is the only product of vectors which produces a vector *and* is invariant under rotations?  If so, how could that be proven?  If not, is there some other invariant that is preserved under the cross product, but not any other product of vectors on $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: "Also, using the orientation and metric structure just as for the traditional 3-dimensional cross product, one can in n dimensions take the product of n − 1 vectors to produce a vector perpendicular to all of them. But if the product is limited to non-trivial binary products with vector results, it exists only in three and seven dimensions."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra#Not_necessarily_associative_division_algebras

Comment: @WillJagy I'm willing to bet my professor meant a *binary* product -- and probably even one in $3$ dimensions.  And I don't see what division algebras have to do with anything.  Afterall, there're no inverse elements for the cross product (that I'm aware of).  So surely it doesn't form a division algebra.

Comment: I guess by *product* he meant a binary operation that is compatible in a nice way to other operations like addition (distributive law) etc.

Comment: It is certainly true that componentwise multiplication is a perfectly good product (it's the product in the ring $\Bbb R^3 = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$), and there are others as well as you noted. So this has to mean something like the only product with particular geometric properties, as other comments have said. (It's also a product that's compatible with differential forms on $\Bbb R^3$.)

Comment: Oh well.  I'll just ask my professor exactly what he meant tomorrow.  Thanks you guys.  If a mod wants to delete this question, that's fine with me.